# PPTP VPN from Ubuntu cannot connect

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vpn, kubuntu, networkmanager, pptp

I'm trying to configure under Linux (Kubuntu 9.10) a VPN I already use from Windows.

I installed the network-manager-pptp package and added the VPN under Network Manager.
These are the parameters under "advanced" button:

- Authentication Methods: PAP, CHAP, MSCHAP, MSCHAP2, EAP
  (I also tried "MSCHAP, MSCHAP2")
- Use MPPE Encryption: yes
- Crypto: Any
- Use stateful encryption: no
- Allow BSD compression: yes
- Allow Deflate compression: yes
- Allow TCP header compression: yes
- Send PPP echo packets: no

When I try to connnect it doesn't work and this is what I get in the system log:

```
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 4931
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' just appeared, activating connections
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pppd[4932]  Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 3
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pppd[4932]  pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN connection 'MYVPN' (Connect) reply received.
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager     SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena NetworkManager     SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pppd[4932]  Using interface ppp0
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pppd[4932]  Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pptp[4934]  nm-pptp-service-4931 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
2010-04-08 13:53:47 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 1, peer's call ID 14800).
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  CHAP authentication succeeded
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  CHAP authentication succeeded
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  LCP terminated by peer
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:929]: Call disconnect notification received (call id 14800)
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:788]: Received Stop Control Connection Request.
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 4 'Stop-Control-Connection-Reply'
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pptp[4927]  nm-pptp-service-4918 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  Modem hangup
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  Connection terminated.
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager     SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena pppd[4932]  Exit.
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 6
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  VPN plugin state change reason: 0
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <WARN>  connection_state_changed(): Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
2010-04-08 13:53:48 pcelena NetworkManager  <info>  Policy set 'Auto eth0' (eth0) as default for routing and DNS.
2010-04-08 13:54:01 pcelena NetworkManager  <debug> [1270727641.001390] ensure_killed(): waiting for vpn service pid 4931 to exit
2010-04-08 13:54:01 pcelena NetworkManager  <debug> [1270727641.001479] ensure_killed(): vpn service pid 4931 cleaned up
```

The error that sticks out here is "**pppd[4932]  LCP terminated by peer**".

Does anyone has suggestion on what can be the problem and how to make it work?

Comment: Are there logs from the server side available ?

Comment: I don't have access to the server.

Answer (score 3):

I had almost exactly the same problem and here's how I solved it:

I enabled 128 bit encryption with all other options enabled.

Now it works! :)